# Вывод страниц в модальное окно wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Добрый день
Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть слайдер в котором 40 итемов (картинок), каждая картинка это отдельная страница
При нажатии на картинку открывается модальное окно в котором отображается контент определенной страницы
я это сделал для двух страниц, но они отображаются обе в модалке, что не есть хорошо

```
<div id="modal_form">
    <span id="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-5px" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <?php
         $args = array(
             'include' => '46,98',
         ); 
         $pages = get_pages($args);
         foreach($pages as $page) { 
            echo $page->post_content;
            echo do_shortcode('[_moneyGame]'); 
         }  
         wp_reset_postdata();
    ?></div><div id="overlay"></div>
```

ну соответсвенно в js стоит обработчик на картинки по клику

Как можно в одной и тойже модалке отображать контент с разных страниц?

Answer (score 0):

Это делают посредством ajax - вызов php кода из javascript. Краткое начальное руководство можно найти [здесь](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Answer (score 0):

В интернете есть много инструкций того, как это можно реализовать. Например:

- https://allurewebsolutions.com/blog/open-wordpress-post-modal-without-plugin
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/open-wordpress-posts-in-bootstrap-modal
- https://www.themepunch.com/faq/open-post-content-inside-modal-popup/

поиск осуществлял через google, поисковая фраза "**wordpress open post in modal window**"